# How to filter a combo box in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a VB.NET application and when the form first loads it will populate the combo box with all results from the SQL query. I need it so as the user types it will continue to filter the combo box so shorten the list. I also need it to use a wildcard in the front and end of what the user typed so the user can type 1004 and get results for anything that has 1004 no matter if its in the front of end of the result.

```vb
Private Sub DiePartNum_cbx_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DiePartNum_cbx.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Enter key press when the user selects an item
    Dim diePartNum As String = DiePartNum_cbx.SelectedItem?.ToString()

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(diePartNum) Then
        LoadDieLotValues(diePartNum)
        DieLot_cbx.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub DiePartNum_cbx_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DiePartNum_cbx.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
        Dim typedValue As String = DiePartNum_cbx.Text.Trim()

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(typedValue) Then
            ' Check if the typed value is present in the drop-down list
            Dim selectedValue As Object = DiePartNum_cbx.Items.Cast(Of Object)().FirstOrDefault(Function(item) String.Equals(item?.ToString(), typedValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

            If selectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
                DiePartNum_cbx.SelectedItem = selectedValue
            Else
                LoadDieLotValues(typedValue)
            End If
        End If

        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub LoadAllDiePartNumbers()
    ' Query the database to retrieve all distinct DiePartNum values
    Dim query As String = "SELECT i.Item1, l.Item1, o.Item1 FROM database1 i " &
        "INNER JOIN database2 l ON i.Item1 = l.Item1 AND i.Item2 = l.Item2 " &
        "INNER JOIN database3 o ON i.Item1 = o.Item1 AND i.Item2 = o.Item2 " &
        "WHERE i.Item2 = @SiteValue AND i.Item1 LIKE 'PJ%' AND l.Item1 IS NOT NULL AND l.Item3 IS NULL"

    sqlControl.AddParam("@SiteValue", SiteValue)
    sqlControl.ExecQuery(query)

    If Not sqlControl.HasException() AndAlso sqlControl.CSIDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ' Clear the existing items in the DiePartNum_cbx ComboBox
        DiePartNum_cbx.Items.Clear()

        ' Use HashSet to keep track of added item numbers
        Dim addedItemNumbers As New HashSet(Of String)

        ' Add the retrieved DiePartNum values to the DiePartNum_cbx ComboBox
        For Each row As DataRow In sqlControl.CSIDT.Rows
            Dim diePartNum As String = row("Item").ToString()

            ' Check if the item number is already added before adding it again
            If Not addedItemNumbers.Contains(diePartNum) Then
                DiePartNum_cbx.Items.Add(diePartNum)
                addedItemNumbers.Add(diePartNum)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please look at the preview of your question and don't submit if the formatting is a mess. If you don't know how to format code on this site, consult the Help Center to learn.

Comment: Your simplest option would be to simply bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the `ComboBox`. You can then handle the appropriate event and set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. At first my approach was having a query run each time they typed in a letter but that slowed down the application a lot so I decided to run a query when the user selects the drop down list to view the items. This allows the query to run after the user is done typing

```
Private Sub DiePartNum_cbx_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DiePartNum_cbx.DropDown
    ' Check if the text in the combo box is empty
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(DiePartNum_cbx.Text) Then
        ' If it's empty, load all DiePartNum values
        LoadAllDiePartNumbers()
    Else
        ' Query the database to retrieve all distinct DiePartNum values
        Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT i.Item1 FROM Database1 i " &
        "INNER JOIN Database2 l ON i.Item1 = l.Item1 AND i.Item2 = l.Item2 " &
        "INNER JOIN Database3 o ON i.Item1 = o.Item1 AND i.Item2 = o.Item2 " &
        "WHERE i.Item2 = @SiteValue AND i.Item1 LIKE '%' + @PartNum + '%' AND l.Item1 IS NOT NULL AND l.Item3 IS NULL"
        SQL.AddParam("@SiteValue", GlobalVariables.SiteGV)
        SQL.AddParam("@PartNum", DiePartNum_cbx.Text)
        SQL.ExecQuery(query)

        ' Clear the existing items in the DiePartNum_cbx ComboBox
        DiePartNum_cbx.Items.Clear()

        ' Use HashSet to keep track of added item numbers
        Dim addedItemNumbers As New HashSet(Of String)

        ' Add the retrieved DiePartNum values to the DiePartNum_cbx ComboBox
        For Each row As DataRow In SQL.CSIDT.Rows
            Dim newDiePartNum As String = row("Item").ToString()

            ' Check if the item number is already added before adding it again
            If Not addedItemNumbers.Contains(newDiePartNum) Then
                DiePartNum_cbx.Items.Add(newDiePartNum)
                addedItemNumbers.Add(newDiePartNum)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```